# Как сбросить пароль bios на ноутбуке Asus?

Tags: bios, ноутбук

На материнской плате нет никаких перемычек, при удалении батареи биоса сбрасывается только время.

Ноутбук - Asus x550lb.

Самый верный способ, это ввод rest кода, который можно ввести в поле которое можно вызвать нажатием alt + R, но в моем случаи при нажатии этой комбинации ничего не происходит.

Comment: Руководство пользователя https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X550LA/R_eManual_X550LA_LB_LC_VER7926.pdf страницы 90 и 91.

Comment: @Akina Я ценю любую помощь, но там нет ни слова о том, что мне необходимо.

Comment: Вы можете зайти в Advanced options (стр. 91)? Какие именно варианты Вы там видите?

Comment: Ещё попробуйте выключить ноут, перевернуть его, на обратной стороне, возле надписи `CMOS`, найти отверстие, тонким предметом (зубочистка подойдёт) нажмите кнопку внутри отверстия и удерживайте ее ~ 10 секунд.

Comment: @Akina Доступа к подобному меню нет, так как при F9 вызывается меню восстановления windows, она тут не при чем. И к сожалению на мат. плате нет никаких кнопок \ переключателей :-(